# Building solutions to forth order ODEs out of products of solutions to second order ODEs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Let $r$, $A$, $A_0$,$A_1$ and $A_2$ be real numbers.

By generalizing the approach given in my answer to [How can I solve the following higher order ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919096/how-can-i-solve-the-following-higher-order-ode/2948413#2948413) I have found the following.

Define the following functions :
\begin{eqnarray}
a_2(x) &:=& 4 A^2 A_0 r^2 x^{2 r-2}&+4 A A_1 r^2 x^{r-2}&+\frac{(4 A_2-1) r^2+1}{x^2}\\
a_3(x) &:=& 12 A^2 A_0 (r-1) r^2 x^{2 r-3}&+6 A A_1 (r-2) r^2 x^{r-3}&+\frac{3 \left((1-4 A_2) r^2-1\right)}{x^3}\\
a_4(x)&:=&4 A^2 A_0 (r-1) r^2 (2 r-3) x^{2 r-4}&+2 AA_1 (r-3) (r-2) r^2 x^{r-4}&+\frac{3 (4 A_2-1) r^2+3}{x^4}
\end{eqnarray}
Now consider a following fourth order Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE):
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^4 v(x)}{d x^4} + a_2(x) \frac{d^2 v(x)}{d x^2} + a_3(x) \frac{d^1 v(x)}{d x^1} + a_4(x) v(x)=0
\end{equation}

Then the solution to the ODE above reads:
\begin{equation}
v(x)= C_1 v_1(x)^2 + C_2 v_2(x)^2 + C_{1,2} v_1(x) v_2(x)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
v_{1,2}(x) := x^{\frac{1-r}{2}} \cdot y_{1,2}(A x^r)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
y_1(x) &=& M_{-\frac{\imath A_1}{2\sqrt{A_0}},-\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{-1+4 A_2}}(2\imath \sqrt{A_0} x)\\
y_2(x) &=& W_{-\frac{\imath A_1}{2\sqrt{A_0}},-\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{-1+4 A_2}}(2\imath \sqrt{A_0} x)
\end{eqnarray}
where $M_{\cdot,\cdot}(x)$ and $W_{\cdot,\cdot}(x)$ are Whittaker functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function .

The code snippet below provides a verification:

```
In[970]:= r =.; A =.; A0 =.; A1 =.; A2 =.;
{a2[x_], a3[x_], 
   a4[x_]} = {(1 + (-1 + 4 A2) r^2)/x^2 + 4 A A1 r^2 x^(-2 + r) + 
    4 A^2 A0 r^2 x^(-2 + 2 r), (3 (-1 + (1 - 4 A2) r^2))/x^3 + 
    6 A A1 (-2 + r) r^2 x^(-3 + r) + 
    12 A^2 A0 (-1 + r) r^2 x^(-3 + 2 r), (3 + 3 (-1 + 4 A2) r^2)/
    x^4 + 2 A A1 r^2 (-3 + r) (-2 + r) x^(-4 + r) + 
    4 A^2 A0 r^2 (-1 + r) (-3 + 2 r) x^(-4 + 2 r)};
y1[x_] = WhittakerM[-((I A1)/(2 Sqrt[A0])), -(1/2) I Sqrt[-1 + 4 A2], 
   2 I Sqrt[A0] x];
y2[x_] = WhittakerW[-((I A1)/(2 Sqrt[A0])), -(1/2) I Sqrt[-1 + 4 A2], 
   2 I Sqrt[A0] x];
v1[x_] = x^((1 - r)/2) y1[A x^r];
v2[x_] = x^((1 - r)/2) y2[A x^r];
FullSimplify[(D[#, {x, 4}] + a2[x] D[#, {x, 2}] + a3[x] D[#, {x, 1}] +
      a4[x] #) & /@ {v1[x]^2, v2[x]^2, v1[x] v2[x]}]

Out[976]= {0, 0, 0}
```

Now what we have done in here is the following. We rescaled the abscissa and the ordinates of Whittaker functions and then constructed a symmetric product of those functions, which in turn satisfies a forth order ODE. This procedure follows pretty much the ideas from [1].

Update: Here is another example of a 4th order linear ODE that has a solution in terms of a symmetric product of solutions to 2nd order ODEs. 
Let $n$, $w$ and $A$ be parameters. Now consider a following ODE:
\begin{eqnarray}
y^{(4)}(x) + \frac{w}{x^2} y^{(2)}(x) + \frac{-8 (n+6) w-5 n (n+2) (n+4)}{16 x^3} y^{(1)}(x) + \left( 4 A x^{2 n}-\frac{3 \left(n^2-16\right) \left(7 n^2+16 n+16 w\right)}{256 x^4}\right) y(x)=0
\end{eqnarray}

The fundamental set of solutions to this ODE is given by
$\left\{ y_{1,\eta_1}(x) \cdot y_{2,\eta_2}(x)\right\}$ for $\eta_1=-1,1$ and $\eta_2=-1,1$ where:
\begin{eqnarray}
y_{1,\eta}(x)&:=& x^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{8}} \cdot J_{\eta \frac{\sqrt{-3 n^2-12 n-8 w+8}}{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{(n+2)^2}}}(\frac{2 \sqrt[4]{A}}{\sqrt{n^2+4 n+4}}\cdot x^{\frac{n}{2}+1})\\
y_{2,\eta}(x)&:=& x^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{8}} \cdot J_{\eta \frac{\sqrt{-3 n^2-12 n-8 w+8}}{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{(n+2)^2}}}(\frac{2 \sqrt[4]{A} \imath}{\sqrt{n^2+4 n+4}}\cdot x^{\frac{n}{2}+1})
\end{eqnarray}

```
In[790]:= n =.; w =.; A =.; Clear[y1]; Clear[y2]; x =.; eX =.;
y1[eta_, x_] = 
  x^(1/2 - n/8) BesselJ[
    eta Sqrt[8 - 12 n - 3 n^2 - 8 w]/(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(2 + n)^2]), (
     2 A^(1/4) Sqrt[1])/Sqrt[4 + 4 n + n^2] x^(n/2 + 1)];
y2[eta_, x_] = 
  x^(1/2 - n/8) BesselJ[
    eta Sqrt[8 - 12 n - 3 n^2 - 8 w]/(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(2 + n)^2]), (
     2 A^(1/4) Sqrt[-1])/Sqrt[4 + 4 n + n^2] x^(n/2 + 1)];

eX = ((-((3 (-16 + n^2) (16 n + 7 n^2 + 16 w))/(256 x^4)) + 
         4 A x^(2 n)) # + (-5 n (2 + n) (4 + n) - 8 (6 + n) w) /(
       16 x^3) D[#, x] + w /x^2 D[#, {x, 2}] + D[#, {x, 4}]) & /@ {y1[
      1, x] y2[1, x], y1[-1, x] y2[1, x], y1[1, x] y2[-1, x], 
    y1[-1, x] y2[-1, x]};
{n, w, A} = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 3, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
x = RandomReal[{0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
eX


Out[796]= {0.*10^-43 + 0.*10^-43 I, 0.*10^-43 + 0.*10^-43 I, 
 0.*10^-43 + 0.*10^-43 I, 0.*10^-43 + 0.*10^-43 I}
```

Now my question would be the following . Can we construct solutions of any forth order ODE with "polynomial" coefficients in the way we did this in here? For example can we solve the ODE given in here [How can I solve the following higher order ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919096/how-can-i-solve-the-following-higher-order-ode/2948413#2948413) with this method?If yes what other second order ODEs -- rather than the Whittaker ODE --could we be using for that purpose.

[1]M.F. Singer,  Solving Homogeneous Linear Differential Equations in Terms
of Second Order Linear Differential Equations,
Am. J. of Math., 107, 1985, 663-696.